# Printer queuing - RabbitMQ - Design considerations

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue

There is a windows service application that will send the messages received from the RabbitMQ and send the same to printer for printing.

Here I need to develop a UI that will display the current items in the MQ. Here UI will be updated with the current status of each job in the queue.

If there are 10 jobs in which currently 1 is in printing status, I need to display 10 jobs in UI and mark one as "Printing" and display others in the same order they arrived.

Here I am thinking about having a queue with ACK so only if I send ACK, the message should be deleted from the Queue. This will happen in windows service.

But on UI, I need to be in sync with windows service and and display jobs accordingly. I am not sure how to design this sync using RabbitMQ.

I can design another queue but that has to be in sync with items in print queue.

Please provide some suggestion on how to achive this using RabbitMQ

**Edit:**

The service runs on premises and the UI is a web application. There is no way the UI can directly communicate with service and it can happen only through MQ.

Comment: I believe the UI app should contact the service, not the rabbitmq for that.

Comment: @zerkms  Sorry I missed to add the point that service runs on a closed environment and UI is a web app. Wep app and service communicates only through MQ